# What does the 'evolution' property under Turbulent Displace in After Effects do?

Tags: after-effects

It seems to add a ripple effect the more I increase the degree, but would like to read about it somewhere more. Couldn't find anything about it with a google/youtube search that specifically explains it. What is it supposed to control precisely?